# Image does not update (PHP)

Tags: php, image

I'm currently working on a system right now that involves the use of many images. There are some images (specially background images) that I used where when I updated the images that includes the picture path, the image does not update. I checked the path if it's correct and even the folder containing the picture.

However, I noticed that when I clear the history of the picture, that is the time the picture becomes accurate. I did not use any session or cookie for saving my image. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Browser cache? Have you tried clearing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some parameter to image link and change this parameter after image update ;)

Example :

`src="image.png?timestamp=20180602" ;`